# GridGain SQL Transform Query Limitations

Tags: sql, gridgain

I am running into an issue with doing an SQL Transform Query. I have a replicated Cache setup with thousands of cached items in various Classes. When I run a transform query that returns specific (summary) items from Classes on the Cache, it looks like the query executes just fine and returns a Collection. However, when I iterate through the Collection, after 2,048 items, the individual items in the Collection (which used to be Cast'able until then) are now simple a 'GridCacheQueryResponseEntry', which I can't seem to cast anymore...

Is 2,048 items the limit for a Transform Query Result Set in GridGain?

here's the code I use to query/transform the cache items (Simplified a bit). This works for exactly 2048 items and then throws an Exception:

```
GridCacheQuery<Map.Entry<UUID, Object>> TypeQuery = queries.createSqlQuery(Object.class, "from Object where Type = ? and Ident regexp ?");

GridClosure<Map.Entry<UUID, Object>, ReturnObject> Trans = new GridClosure<Map.Entry<UUID, Object>, ReturnGeometry>() {
   @Override public ReturnObject apply(Map.Entry<UUID, Object> e) {
       try {
           ReturnObject tmp = e.getValue().getReturnObject();
            } catch (Exception ex) {ex.getMessage()); }
       return tmp;
       }
};

Collection<ReturnObject> results = TypeQuery .execute(Trans,"VarA","VarB").get();

Iterator iter = results.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
     try {
         Object item = iter.next();
         ReturnObjectpoint = (ReturnObject) item;
     } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no such limitations in GridGain. Whenever you execute a query, you have two options:

- Call `GridCacheQueryFuture.get()` method to get the whole result set as a collection. This works only for relatively small result set, because all the rows in the result set have to be loaded to client node's memory.
- Use `GridCacheFutureMethod.next()` to iterate through result set. In this case results will be acquired from remote nodes page by page. When you finished iteration through a page, it's discarded and next one is loaded. So you have only one page at a time which gives you an opportunity to query  result sets of any size.

As for `GridCacheQueryResponseEntry`, you should not cast to it, because it's an internal GridGain class and is actually a simple implementation of `Map.Entry` interface which represents a key-value pair from GridGain cache.

In case of transform query you will get `Map.Entry` instances only in transformer, while client node will receive already transformed values, so I'm not sure how it's possible to get them during iteration. Can you provide a small code example of how you execute the query?